# If ng-if evaluates to false on load / init, will a dom element still be created before being removed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

This is more in the interest of load time as opposed to bandwidth. I have a lot of ng-when right now and I feel like the watchers are slowing down my application.
I was wondering if ng-if would actually create the associated controllers and then remove it later even if the ng-if evaluates to false from the beginning.
I'm on Angular 1.4 (we'll be migrating to 4 later)
Thanks!

Comment: No. As long as the Angular Expression evaluates as [falsey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) no DOM elements are created. However the AngularJS Expression will be evaluated on each digest cycle possibly multiple times.

Comment: @georgeawg thanks! If I make it a one time binding, it should only run one time; I think that would be pretty neat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. As long as the Angular Expression evaluates as [falsey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) no DOM elements are created. However the AngularJS Expression will be evaluated on each digest cycle possibly multiple times.

If you want to limit the evauations, use [One-time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#one-time-binding):

> An expression that starts with `::` is considered a one-time expression. One-time expressions will stop recalculating once they are stable, which happens after the first digest if the expression result is a non-undefined value.

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - How to benefit from one-time binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#how-to-benefit-from-one-time-binding).